# How to map fields from content type to user Profile

Tags: entities

I am using a content type named `application`

There are some fields I like to map to the users profile to use them with panels.

For example there are fields called:

- name -->textfield
- nickman-->textfield
- birthday--> date
- about-->text with summery
- etc

Now I would like to map the content of these fields to the same fields used in the users profile to display the information the users had entered in their applications.

How could I do that? Where to start to find more about field mappings?

Thank you guys and gals!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the content of the fields in `application` to be saved in the user entity, I can think of a couple of approaches:

1. Use [Rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to copy the values to the user entity when the `application` content is saved.
2. Write a custom module and use [hook_node_update()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7) to add the values to the user entity.

Comment: The rules  approach  is working  perfectly. Thanks!